# White screen when loading converted wordpress theme from html

Tags: html, wordpress, themes, screen

I have a problem **converting html page into wordpress theme**. When loading theme i just see white screen but other previously installed theme looks normal. I read earlier similar subject on stackoverflow  but it seems that it doesnt help me. Can somebody help me solve this problem?

These are my theme files:

```
Theme Name: Vesti
Theme URI: www.komunalacbecej.com
Author: Aljosa Boskovic
Author URI: www.komunalacbecej.com
Description: Twenty Seventeen brings your site to life with immersive featured images and subtle animations. With a focus on business sites, it features multiple sections on the front page as well as widgets, navigation and social menus, a logo, and more. Personalize its asymmetrical grid with a custom color scheme and showcase your multimedia content with post formats. Our default theme for 2017 works great in many languages, for any abilities, and on any device.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: twentyseventeen

*/


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}

body{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #faf6d0;

    padding: 0;
    //background-image: url('images/green.png');
    background-size: cover;
}

header{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#uppermenu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;

}

#uppermenu ul{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#uppermenu ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 540;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#uppermenu ul li:hover{
    color:#156038;
}



#flags{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#flags img{

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#logo{
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;

}

#naziv{
    float: left;
    color: #1a7645;
    height: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #3d874d;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
    border: 2px solid #a4a41b;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #150;

}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fdf742;
}

nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    background: #2a562c;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

nav ul ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5b7e5d;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}

#slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#slidephoto{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#leftbutton{
    width: 5%;
    height:500px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #b3b0b0;
    opacity: .5;
    line-height: 500px;
    z-index: 4;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#rightbutton{
    width: 5%;
    height:500px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #b3b0b0;
    opacity: .5;
    line-height: 500px;
    z-index: 4;
    border-radius: 5px;


}

#leftarrow {
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#rightarrow {
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#leftarrow:hover{
    background: grey;
}

#rightarrow:hover{
    background: grey;
}

#naslov{

    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-indent: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #1a7645;
    font-family: Georgia;
    border-top: 1px solid #1a7645;
    background: #639665;
    color: #e6f3d1;
    padding: 10px 0;

}
#firsttext{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px auto 0  auto;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px 90px;
    color: white;
    background: #6eae49;;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#firsttext span{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1a7645;
}

#delatnosti {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6f3d1;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #6d9e6f;
    padding: 20px ;


    }

.boxes div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #a2b6c0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 210px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: #46545b;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

.boxes div:hover{
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: #dfdede;
}

.boxes a img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 110px;
}

.boxes a p, h3{
    //margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;

} 
.boxes div a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}



#obavestenja{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    //border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-indent: 210px;

}

#mainnews-banner{ 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mainnews-banner h1{
 text-indent: 210px;
 font-family: serif;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#sadrzaj{
    width: 75%;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#vestikolone{
    width: 80%;
}

#glavnavestslika{
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
    background: url("images/slika4.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#glavnavesttekst{
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .6;
}

#glavnavesttekst p{
    color: #ded8d8;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    line-height: 23px;
}

#glavnavesttekst h2{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
    font-family: Georgia;
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#glavnavest {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

#datum{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

#banner{
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    //border: 3px solid green;
    //background: #f1f1f1;
}
#banner img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #9ac0f6;
    border: 1px solid #9ac0f6;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#banner p{

    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Arial;
    background: #fecd61;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

#pastnewspara{

    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    opacity: .9;

}

#pastnews{


    border-top: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width:75%;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    border-top: none;

}

.column{

    width: 25%;
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.column img{
    width: 100%;
    height:140px;
}

.column h3,p{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}


#prognoza{
    clear: both;
    width: 75%;
    background: brown;
    color: #a2b6c0;


    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.weatherwidget-io{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;

}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background: white;
    background: #a2b6c0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 3px solid white;

}

#icons{

    line-height: 130px;


}
#footer i{
    color: #554f4f;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 26px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    color: grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#footer span i{
    padding: 6px;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

/* stranica zelenilo.html */


#submenu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    background: rgba(96,96,96,0.4);
}


#submenu {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 22%;
    background: url('images/leaf3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: .9;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #cfcf05;
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;

}

#submenu ul {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;

}

 #zelenilobody{
    background: url('images/goranski.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1000px;
}

#submenu ul li:hover{
    background-color: grey;
    background: rgba(96,96,96,0.7);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;


}

#navigation nav{
    background-color: #61a239;
}

#zelenilo-naziv #naziv{
    color: #60a23a;
    background-color: rgba(96,96,96,0.7);
}

#zelenilo-uppermenu #uppermenu li{
    color: #60a23a;
    background-color: rgba(96,96,96,0.8);
}

#zelenilo-tekst{
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: rgb(246, 241, 241, 0.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;

}

#zelenilo-tekst p{
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;

}

#zelenilo-tekst ol{
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* stranica vesti.php */

#blognews {

    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

#article {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 20px 0;
}

#article h2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#datumclanka{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#article img{
 height: 120px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 180px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;


}

#article p{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 650px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body>

    <header>

   <img src="images/logofirme.jpg" id="logo">
   <div id="naziv">
   <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    <p>Javno preduzeće za komunalne usluge</p>
  </div>

   <div id="flags">
    <img src="images/serbia.png">
    <img src="images/hungary.png">
   </div>

   <div id="uppermenu">
    <ul>
      <li>Najčešća pitanja</li>
      <li>Korisni linkovi</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>

 </header>
```

**footer.php**

```
 <div id="footer">


   <div id="icons">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
  <span><i class="fa fa-copyright"></i>Design by Aleksey</span>
</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
test
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: `get_header` needs to do at the top of your index.php and `get_footer` needs to go at the bottom. `get_header` is calling your header.php and `get_footer` is calling your footer!

Comment: you need to set header portion in header.php, footer section in footer.php, sidebar section in sidebar.php. index section in index.php.

Comment: But i already have this code in my index.php code. I posted that here:<!-- index.php -->

<?php get_header(); ?>
test
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: I already have header.php page, footer.php page, index.php page and style.css. I posted all the pages in code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try following solutions?

1. In first line of style.css add "/*" before "Theme Name: Vesti". So it will be like

   /*
   Theme Name: Vesti
2. Disable/deactivate all plugins to check if confliction happens between your active theme and plugins. And then enable it one by one if issue happens because of it.
3. Add following line in wp-config.php file for increasing PHP memory limit.

   define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’64M’);